# Concat columns name with BOOLEAN condition

Tags: python, conditional-statements, boolean, dataset

folks. How can I concatenate BOOLEAN columns name to a new column on Pandas?

Original dataset

| Column01 | Column02 |
| --- | --- |
| TRUE | TRUE |
| FALSE | TRUE |

Desired output

| Column01 | Column02 | CONCATENATED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | TRUE | Column01, Column02 |
| FALSE | TRUE | Column02 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


def t(x):
    x["CONCATENATED"] = ", ".join([x.index[i]  for i in range(len(x)) if x.values[i] == True])
    return x


df = pd.DataFrame({"Column01": [True, False], "Column02": [True, True]})

print(df.apply(t, axis=1))
```

OUTPUT:

```
   Column01  Column02        CONCATENATED
0      True      True  Column01, Column02
1     False      True            Column02
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([[True,False],[True,True],[True,False]],columns=['Column01','Column02'])

boolean_column_names = data.columns[0:2]
column_names = []
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    # create list of columns name
    tmp = boolean_column_names[data.iloc[i, :]].to_list()
    # convert them to string
    strings = ','.join(tmp)
    # create list of strings
    column_names.append(strings)

data['CONCATENATED'] = pd.Series(column_names)
```

output:

| Column01 | Column02 | CONCATENATED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | False | Column01 |
| True | true | Column01,Column02 |
| True | False | Column01 |